# Graylog 3.2 REST API sync search

Tags: rest, graylog, graylog3

Is there any documentation or examples how to work with /views/search/sync in Graylog 3.2? The Model Schema is not really self explanotary and https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/configuration/rest_api.html also not really helpful.  I know that /search/universal/relative exists, but I’d like to test new methods.

Comment: Hi AlexSmith.  Asking for recommendations for of site resources is considered off topic for StackOverflow.  Instead, ask about what you are trying to test, what code you have so far (as minimal a code example as possible) and what problem you are having